# show data from database in custom page using prestashop

Tags: php, html, prestashop, template-engine

I have created a page where i want to show listing from database. i have follow the same steps to from this [link](https://iftakharhasan.wordpress.com/2014/04/05/prestashop-create-a-custom-page-without-cms/)  which is working fine. but issue is that   i can't loop data from database in `my tpl file`. In `tpl` file I show listing

```
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

please help me.

Comment: you show us the contents of the controller using ?

Comment: Please open the link i copy each and everything from this link https://iftakharhasan.wordpress.com/2014/04/05/prestashop-create-a-custom-page-without-cms/ . But in this link controller not calling?

Comment: how you have changed the content CustomPageController.php ?

Comment: I am new for prestashop. so In the above link CustomPageController.php not inculding anywhere. Please just guide me how to achieve my target? if you have  other good link or provide me some  piece of code@MatteoEnna

Answer (score 0):

In custom-page.php before: $smarty->display(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'custom-page.tpl');

add:

```
$customer = CustomerCore::getCustomers();

$contact =array();

foreach ($customer as $c){
    $id = AddressCore::getFirstCustomerAddressId($c['id_customer']);
    $contact[] = new AddressCore($id);
}

$smarty->smarty->assign(array('contacts'=>$contact));
```

In custom-page.tpl insert:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
 </tr>
 {foreach $contacts as $contact}
     <tr>
         <td>{$contact->company}</td>
         <td>{$contact->lastname} {$contact->firstname}</td>
         <td>country</td>
     </tr>
 {/foreach}
```

Comment: Thank you i w ill try it. then i will inform you.